# how to filter arrays stored as two lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have to lists of arrays, one is all my data and another one is a filter:

```
data= [array([[12., 2., 7.],
              [9., -1., 0.],
              [2., 0., 4.],
              [14., 2., 1.2]]),
       array([[11., 3., 1.],
              [2., 5., 0.],
              [1., -1., 1.],
              [-8., 0., 6.],
              [2., 3., 3.]])]

filter= [array([2., 0., 5.]),
         array([3., -1.])]
```

I want to only keep values of each array of my `data`, that their second column (`data[i][:,1]`) is equal to one the values of the same array  from the `filter` (all values of `filter[i]`). I want to have the following output:

```
out = [array([[12., 2., 7.],
              [2., 0., 4.],
              [14., 2., 1.2]]),
       array([[11., 3., 1.],
              [1., -1., 1.],
              [2., 3., 3.]])]
```

I have tried the following code but it was not successful:

```
out=[]
for a in data:
    for b in filter:
        for c in b:
            if a[:,1]==c:
                bb=a[:,c]
                out=np.append(data,bb)
```

I appreciate any help and contribution in advance.

Comment: Why you have nested arrays in the filter?

Comment: Dear @Dani Mesejo, because in some cases different numbers can be applied as a filter. For each array stored in my data, I have an array as a filter. In some cases my filter can be jagged list, so I decided to add all the arrays (both `filter` and `data`) as list.

Comment: I understand, but why this `array([[3., -1.]])` instead of just `array([3., -1.])`?

Comment: Sorry, That is a typo. I made a big mistake. `array([3., -1.])` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to create the masks and then filter using those masks:

```
import numpy as np

data = [np.array([[12., 2., 7.],
                  [9., -1., 0.],
                  [2., 0., 4.],
                  [14., 2., 1.2]]),
        np.array([[11., 3., 1.],
                  [2., 5., 0.],
                  [1., -1., 1.],
                  [-8., 0., 6.],
                  [2., 3., 3.]])]

filter_data = [np.array([2., 0., 5.]),
               np.array([3., -1.])]

# compute the masks
masks = [np.isin(arr[:, 1], filter_arr) for arr, filter_arr in zip(data, filter_data)]

# filter using the masks
result = [arr[mask] for arr, mask in zip(data, masks)]

for filtered_arr in result:
    print(filtered_arr)
```

**Output**

```
[[12.   2.   7. ]
 [ 2.   0.   4. ]
 [14.   2.   1.2]]
[[11.  3.  1.]
 [ 1. -1.  1.]
 [ 2.  3.  3.]]
```